# Why do I get "candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided" compilation error when forwarding functions with C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand function forwarding with lambdas on C++ by running this code:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
int do_something_1(int foo_1, Func&& func, Args&&... args, int foo_0 = 0) { 
    int var_1 = foo_0 + 2 * foo_1; 
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(var_1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};

int main (void) {
    return do_something_1(1, [](int var_1, int local_var) { return (var_1 + local_var); }, 4);
}
```

However it fails with this compilation error:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'int do_something_1(int, Func&&, Args&& ..., int) [with Func = main()::<lambda(int, int)>; Args = {}]':
<source>:11:93:   required from here
<source>:7:36: error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(int, int)>) (int&)'
    7 |     return std::forward<Func>(func)(var_1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:7:36: note: candidate: 'int (*)(int, int)' (conversion)
<source>:7:36: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
<source>:11:30: note: candidate: 'main()::<lambda(int, int)>'
   11 |     return do_something_1(1, [](int var_1, int local_var) { return (var_1 + local_var); }, 4);
      |                              ^
<source>:11:30: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

And I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: OT: Don't forward the function itself, that makes no sense.

Comment: Nothing makes sense. But I want to understand how forwarding works.

Comment: In the call to `do_something_1(...)` is the last argument `4` one of the `args` or is it `foo_0`? Skip the lambda call, just print the value of `foo_0` to check. Also print the value of `sizeof...(Args)` to see how many arguments are passed for it.

Comment: It should be local_var

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A functor could have `&` and `&&` overloads for `operator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-terminal function parameter packs are a "non-deduced context" ([[temp.deduct.type]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#deduct.type-5)):

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - [...]
> - A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-list.

This means that the `4` which you pass as an argument will *not* be used to deduce `Args`, but is instead bound to `foo_0`.

Technically you can make this compile by providing template arguments explicitly:

```
int main (void) {
    return do_something_1<int(*)(int,int), int>(1, [](int var_1, int local_var) { return (var_1 + local_var); }, 4);
}
```

This works because the non-capturing lambda can convert to a function pointer, and explicitly supplying `int` as a second template argument causes the `4` to bind to `args...` instead of `foo_0`.

But in general I'd recommend avoiding non-terminal function parameter packs when possible.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with forwarding. Its just making the error more difficult to spot.

You are calling

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
int do_something_1(int foo_1, Func&& func, Args&&... args, int foo_0 = 0)
```

via

```
do_something_1(1, ...lambda..., 4);
```

ie, `foo_1` is `1`, `foo_0` is `4` and `sizeof...(args)==0`.

Not sure what you wanted to pass to the lambda. However, the issue is that you pass only 1 when 2 arguments are expected.

Comment: How should I pass the second argument?

Comment: @Medicalphysicist as I said, I dont know what you wanted to pass, which is the second argument to be passed to the lambda?