# Compilation error when forwarding functions with C++11: using variables from templates in lambda

Tags: c++, c++11

This is the toy program that I try to compile:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
int do_something_1(int foo_1, Func&& func, Args&&... args, int foo_0 = 0) { 
    int var_1 = foo_0 + 2 * foo_1; 
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(var_1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
int do_something_2(int foo_2, Func&& func, Args&&... args) { 
    int var_2 = 10 - foo_2; 
    return do_something_1(3, std::forward<Func>(func)(var_2, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
};


int main (void) {
    return do_something_2(1, [&](int var_1, int var_2) { return (var_1 * var_2); });
}
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'int do_something_2(int, Func&&, Args&& ...) [with Func = main()::<lambda(int, int)>; Args = {}]':
<source>:18:83:   required from here
<source>:13:54: error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(int, int)>) (int&)'
   13 |     return do_something_1(3, std::forward<Func>(func)(var_2, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
      |                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:30: note: candidate: 'main()::<lambda(int, int)>'
   18 |     return do_something_2(1, [](int var_1, int var_2) { return (var_1 * var_2); });
      |                              ^
<source>:18:30: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

It is an extended version of another toy program that gave me some troubles: [Why do I get "candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided" compilation error when forwarding functions with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76033519/why-do-i-get-candidate-expects-2-arguments-1-provided-compilation-error-when)

I want to multiply var2 = 10 - 1 = 9 (line 11), var1 = 0 + 2 * 3 = 6 (line 5), result = 6 * 9 = 54 (line 17)

I don't know how to solve it neither where I can find examples/tutorials in the internet.

Comment: The lambda wants 2 arguments, you pass 1, `var_2`. Notice `args` is empty. It's answered already https://stackoverflow.com/a/76033564/6752050 and you repeat the same issue.

Comment: isnt it the same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76033519/why-do-i-get-candidate-expects-2-arguments-1-provided-compilation-error-when ?

Comment: what is the aim? Why is `args...` not last in the list ?

Comment: How does the argument after the variadic work?  Does C++ allow `foo_0` in this case? `(int foo_1, Func&& func, Args&&... args, int foo_0 = 0)`...... (I always thought that variadic arguments come last)

Comment: I want to use var_1 and var_2, which are defined in the templates, in the way that lambda expresses. I have edited the question.

Comment: You seem to want `std::bind` instead of `std::forward` in `do_something_2`.

Comment: What numbers do you want to multiply inside the lambda? Where do you believe they are passed to the lambda? Note `Args` is always an empty pack so you can get rid of it altogether for the sake of the demonstration.

Comment: I want to use the results of var_1 and var_2, which are defined in do_something_1 and do_something_2

Comment: Please **show the numbers**. "I want to multiply 42 and 27 and these numbers are passed to the lambda at line 17". This kind of sentence.

Comment: `std::forward<Func>(func)(var_2, std::forward<Args>(args)...` calls the function but you want to pass a callable to `do_something_1`

Comment: You cannot pass parameters to the same single function in two separate statements. Functions do not work this way (in C++ at least). You seem to be trying to get around the fact but lambdas, templates, parameter packs and all other shiny toys won't help you one bit. You need a *single* function call that passes *two* parameters to your lambda. These parameters may *originate* at different place in the code, but in the end they must come together to a call of the form `func(expr1, expr2)`. (This call may be hidden inside the implementation of `std::bind` for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says:

> candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided

When you call `do_something_2`:

```
do_something_2(1, [&](int var_1, int var_2) { return (var_1 * var_2); })
```

You don't pass anything for `args...`. So when you call the closure:

```
std::forward<Func>(func)(var_2, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

`args...` expands to nothing, so you're only passing a single argument.

But what you really want is not to call `func` inside `do_something_2`, but to pass a new closure which captures `var_2` and `func`:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
int do_something_1(int foo_1, Func&& func, Args&&... args, int foo_0 = 0) { 
    int var_1 = foo_0 + 2 * foo_1; 
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(var_1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};

template<typename Func>
int do_something_2(int foo_2, Func&& func) { 
    int var_2 = 10 - foo_2; 
    return do_something_1(3, [&](auto&&... args) { return std::forward<Func>(func)(var_2, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); });
};


int main (void) {
    return do_something_2(1, [&](int var_1, int var_2) { return (var_1 * var_2); });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use var_1 and var_2 from the templates as expressed by lambda?

Comment: You mean something like this? https://godbolt.org/z/f5MbbGoxd

Comment: The result is correct. Thanks again! Can you edit your answer and I will accept it please?

Comment: This is a toy program and seems nonsensical. However, instead of criticizing it or analysing it superficially, for the second time you display your excellent knowledge on C++11 and help me solve it. This helps me a lot with another real, complex and useful program. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we get rid of all the shiny bells and whistles that only distract , you are essentially trying to do this:

```
int func (int var1, int var2) { return var1 * var2; }
int do_something_1 (int (*pf1)(int)) { return pf(17); }
int do_something_2 (int (*pf2)(int, int)) { return pf(42); }

int main() { return do_something_2(func); }
```

This kind of thing works in languages like Haskell that has [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) built in, but C++ doesn't work this way. You need to explicitly perform currying in your own code.

One way to do so is using `std::bind`

```
template <typename Func>
int do_something_1 (Func f1) 
{ 
   return f1(17); 
}

int do_something_2 (int (*pf2)(int, int)) 
{ 
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    return std::bind(pf2, 42, _1); 
}
```

Another (arguably better) way is to do it with a lambda.

```
int do_something_2 (int (*pf2)(int, int)) 
{ 
    return do_something_1([&](int var2) { return pf2(42, var2); }
}
```

Many things are omitted from the example, like perfect forwarding of callable objects. Add them to taste.